# Regular Expression in Notepad++ to find "; Capital letter in cyrillic"

Tags: notepad++

I want to find in Notepad++ with regular expression the following:
`; Capital letter in Cyrillic`

Example: `; Васудева`

When I use `; \L` I also find results with `; <M>` which is not working for me since there are many tags with `<`

I also tried `[;]+ [A-Z]+` but I receive the following error:

> `Find: Can't find text "[;]+ [A-Z]+"`

I want to find only `; uppercase/capital letters in Cyrillic` without numbers, special characters, etc.

The error is the following:

> `Find: Can't find text "[;]+ [A-Z]+"`

Regular expression option is enabled and also match case and wrap around are enabled. I forgot to mention that the symbols are in
Cyrillic. I came to what I really need: `; [А-Я]` check Match case check Wrap around check Regular expression.

Also I have another specific case where I have diacritic symbols in Cyrillic which are not part of `[А-Я]` which I don't know how to find.

Comment: Notepad++ questions are valid in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyrillic letters are within unicode range `\u0400 (Ѐ)` - `\u04FF (ӿ)`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script

The uppercase cyrillic letters are within range `\u0400 (Ѐ)` - `\u042F (Я)`, included diacritics. May be some other characters, for example `\u04E4 (Ӥ)` but I'm not sure.

In Notepad++ you can use `[\x{0400}-\x{042F}]` to match Cyrillic uppercase

and  `; [\x{0400}-\x{042F}]` to match semi-colon, space, uppercase.

If you want to match also `Ӥ`, use `[\x{0400}-\x{042F}\u04E4]`.
If you want orher characters, add them in the character class.

##### don't forget to tick `Match case`